# X-Access-Token Request Failure with Python

Tags: python, httprequest, token

I have a request URI and a token. If I use:

```
curl -X GET \
 -H 'X-Access-Token: __API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY__' \
 'https://eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search?method=both&street-address=316+W.+Washington+Ave.+Madison,+WI'
```

etc., I get a 200 and view the corresponding JSON data. However, when I try to access this data via a python script I keep getting 400 and 401 error codes.

I think there is something wrong with how I am formatting the HTTP Request Header for authentication. Here are some of the details listed on the site:

EatStreet API is a suite of stateless JSON endpoints, requested over HTTPS. The production API is simply hosted on https://eatstreet.com under the /publicapi/v1 path.

Authentication
Every request to EatStreet API must be authenticated with an access token. New developers should go here to receive an access token.

Authentication Option: HTTP Request Header
Include the following request header: X-Access-Token: {access token}.

Authentication Option: Query Parameter
Include the following URL query parameter: access-token={access token}.

Here is a link to the EatStreat API documentation: https://developers.eatstreet.com/

I think there is an issue with my syntax, but I've tried so many different variations to format the code and I keep coming up with either a 400 or 401 status code.

This is the script I have currently.

```
api_url = 'https://eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search'
apiKey = '__API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY__'

headers = {'X-Access-Token': apiKey}

def get_restaurant_info():

    response = requests.get(api_url, headers = headers)

    print(response.status_code)
```

I am expecting a JSON file with the format: { "address": Address, "restaurants": Restaurant[] }

Instead, I am getting a bad request HTTP status code.

Comment: you forgot `?method=both&street-address=316+W.+Washington+Ave.+Madison,+WI'`

Comment: on page https://curl.trillworks.com/ you can convert `curl` to python's requests and other languages

Comment: link to documentation gives me error message - maybe server has problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(response.text)` will show you the error. You needed to add an address or lattitude/longitude coordinates. The following works.

```
api_url = 'https://eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search?method=both&street-address=316+W.+Washington+Ave.+Madison,+WI'
apiKey = '__API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY__'

headers = {'X-Access-Token': apiKey}

def get_restaurant_info():

    response = requests.get(api_url, headers = headers)

    print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks! That got it working. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.